# What is the URL for Titanium SDK 5.3.0.RC on the continuous builds server?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I tried going to build.appcelerator.net like it says in the Appcelerator docs but all I see is a "Welcome to nginx!" message. I would reslly like to see if the release fixes an Android bug I have.

Thanks for any help/advice.

Answer (score 2):

This is the URL: [Appcelerator Build Server](http://builds.appcelerator.com/#5_3_X)